# Asp.net Web Api controller action authorize by web config settings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I have a controller action and I want to use changeable authorization via web config settings.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Authorize]
    public Product FindProduct(id) {}
}   

<appSettings>
  <add key="authorize" value="yes"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Create your own custom Authorize Attribute by inheriting Authorize attribute. And in your custom implementation, check for this web.config flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own `AuthorizeWithConfig` attribute that inherits from `Authorize` attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeWithConfigAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _configKey;

    public AuthorizeWithConfigAttribute(string configKey)
    {
        _configKey = configKey;
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Will be read from configuration
        bool requireAuthorization;

        // Skip authorization if
        // (1) Found the specified key in app settings
        // (2) Could parse app setting value into a boolean
        // (3) App setting value is set to FALSE
        var skipAuthorization =               
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ContainsKey(configKey) 
            && bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey],
                             out requireAuthorization) 
            && !requireAuthorization;

        return skipAuthorization ? true : base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for your controller actions:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, AuthorizeWithConfig("App:RequireAuthorization")]
    public Product FindProduct(id) {}
}
```

Assuming that in app settings you have an `App:RequireAuthorization` setting that takes boolean values:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="App:RequireAuthorization" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```