# Web api authorize via web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I want that the access to controllers/actions is only possible for authenticated and authorized users with specific role. Because I don't want to change required role on every controller/action every time when required role is changed

Can I authorize my all controllers/actions in web api just adding:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="admin" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

in web.config?

I'm using web api project inside asp.net mvc project so I wonder if both using the same web.config.

Also any links to official documentation will be nice because I not found any that mention about web.config :(

- my webapi package version 5.2.3

Comment: official documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api, https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security just to start with

Comment: yes I checked it but there is not information if I can do it in web.config or not  :(

Comment: well there's your answer then...

Comment: Just because I did not find any information does not mean that it does not exist. Maybe I can not find it because of lack of knowledge. That's why I ask this question to find out. From your answer I can conclude that I can not do that. Right?

Comment: Well it's not in the official documentation, which I assumed meant it probably wasn't supported. But that's not the same as it not being possible. This answer looks like it's trying something similar... https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508534/5947043 . If it doesn't work you can still put a universal authorisation attribute on all your API controllers and actions globally with one line, you don't need to add it to all of them individually.

Comment: Related: [Asp.net Web Api controller action authorize by web config settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34672031). You can always build your own `IAuthorizationFilter` that reads the legacy ASP.NET file-based authorization settings from web.config and applies those roles. But since Web Api is not file-based, only authorization filters can be used to control authorization.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I tested authorization in web.config using  `<authorization>` and `<location>` tags and both are seem to work. I used fiddler to check if I can get access anonymously and I didn't get access when authorization is set in web.config. Why it works? Or there is possible case where it won't work? Is is because it is mvc application with webapi controller?